# Unable to create/open lock file, Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running

Tags: bash, mongodb, terminal

Unable to create/open lock file, Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?

Showing the following error,

```
/Users/hackintosh01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/hackintosh01/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/Users/hackintosh01/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Volumes/Mac\ Data/mongodb/bin/:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/hackintosh01/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
    Hackintoshs-iMac-2:~ hackintosh01$ mongod
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.814+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=18926 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Hackintoshs-iMac-2.local
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.815+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.10
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.815+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.815+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.815+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.815+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.815+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.815+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.815+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.815+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.826+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
    2018-02-28T17:54:21.826+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
    Hackintoshs-iMac-2:~ hackintosh01$ mongod --dbpath /data/db
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.572+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=18935 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Hackintoshs-iMac-2.local
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.573+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.10
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.573+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.573+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.573+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.573+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.573+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.573+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.573+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.573+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/data/db" } }
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.585+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
    2018-02-28T17:57:24.585+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Comment: so, is it running? does mongodb have permissions to write to `/data/db/` ? Did you check similar answers https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unable+to+create%2Fopen+lock+file%2C+Permission+denied+Is+a+mongod+instance+already+running ?

Comment: No, it is not  running, I have checked permissions for this folder, and now its works fine, This stuck me for a hour... `sudo chmod 777 /data/db`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked with the permissions for the `/data/db` folder, and now its works fine.

<strike>*sudo chmod 777 /data/db*</strike>

**Updated**
Changed ownership to specific user

> sudo chown -R <USERNAME> /data/db

Comment: Whatever your problem is, **granting everyone on the system write access to system resources is a *terrible* idea** and probably a fireable offense in many commercial organizations.  **`chmod 777` is basically *never* right** and you should instead figure out the *minimal* permissions you need to grant in order to satisfy your specific requirements.

Comment: @tripleee I do this as a quick survival on my **development phase only**, corrected the permission issues on the **production server** with **minimal** permissions...

Comment: Not my downvote but correcting the answer to recommend correct permissions should at least prevent you from easily receiving more downvotes. Deleting the question might be the simplest fix, though.

Comment: yeah.. @tripleee Updated my answer